# How to Convert Java Object in to GeoJSON (Required by d3 Graph)

Tags: java, json, d3.js, geojson

I want to convert **java List** object into **D3 GeoJSON**.
Is there any java api available that help to convert java object to GeoJSON object.
I want to display graph in d3.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. A list is a generic data structure that could contain anything, GeoJSON is for geographical data. In general, you probably want to use GIS software such as [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) to do such a conversion.

Comment: thank you for you reply..  I am create the application using java. and my data store in database and using those data i wont to display graph in d3 but d3 require data in JSON format so i wont to convert data in to JSON. So is there any api avaliable using that i convert data in json that accept by D3

Comment: You can use the GeoJSON POJOS for Jackson from Opendatalab, https://github.com/opendatalab-de/geojson-jackson

Comment: RFC7946 1.4 requires the type to be "FeatureCollection" (case sensitive).

Answer (score 14):

GeoJSON is very simple; a general JSON library should be all you need.  Here's how you could construct a list of Points using the json.org code (http://json.org/java/):

```
    JSONObject featureCollection = new JSONObject();
    try {
        featureCollection.put("type", "featureCollection");
        JSONArray featureList = new JSONArray();
        // iterate through your list
        for (ListElement obj : list) {
            // {"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-94.149, 36.33]}
            JSONObject point = new JSONObject();
            point.put("type", "Point");
            // construct a JSONArray from a string; can also use an array or list
            JSONArray coord = new JSONArray("["+obj.getLon()+","+obj.getLat()+"]");
            point.put("coordinates", coord);
            JSONObject feature = new JSONObject();
            feature.put("geometry", point);
            featureList.put(feature);
            featureCollection.put("features", featureList);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.error("can't save json object: "+e.toString());
    }
    // output the result
    System.out.println("featureCollection="+featureCollection.toString());
```

This will output something like this:

```
{
"features": [
    {
        "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
                -94.149, 
                36.33
            ], 
            "type": "Point"
        }
    }
], 
"type": "featureCollection"
}
```

Comment: Maybe the geojson format referred to in the answer is a little outdated, but as of 2017, we would have to add `feature.put("type","Feature")` for this to work. Just added it as I stumbled upon the answer today.