# return GeoJSON from Java servlet

Tags: java, gis

In my database there are records having lat, lng columns. On the middle tier I use Tomcat/Servlets. Client side I use Leaflet.

I want the servlet to create a GeoJSON response for all the records (lat, lng).

Is there a tool available? Or, should I do it manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you google for `geojson java` you get these libs for example:

https://github.com/opendatalab-de/geojson-jackson

https://github.com/mapfish/java-geojson

But if you only need some coordinates, you could also use something like this:

[How to Convert Java Object in to GeoJSON (Required by d3 Graph)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311526/how-to-convert-java-object-in-to-geojson-required-by-d3-graph)

Comment: Thanks Christiaan, to be honest I need something more: I want to merge several points (lat, lng) into a polygon (area) and return this to my client (Leafet). The result should be, that not individual points are displayed, but instead the area they compose. Of course, there are GIS databases, but I want to do it in Java on my Tomcat. So, sorry for the 'wrong question', my intention was to start with an easy question and thereafter the next...

Comment: It seems that the mapfish library can handle polygons since it uses the JTS library: http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm